# Avoid inserting cells while using each in Jxls

Tags: jxls

I have been using jxls for my Excel based reports. 
I am facing a problem with a particular report where the original template has 31 columns for days in a month followed by columns that do certain calculations based on the data in the day columns.

While I am able to insert data in the 31 columns, the problem is that the columns beyond keep shifting right.

I want to be able to insert data in the existing column space and not create new columns.
Appreciate help with this.

Comment: You may also raise a feature request in Jxls issue tracker https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues

Answer (score 0):

"I am able to insert data in the 31 columns, the problem is that the columns beyond keep shifting right."
This is a default feature of jxls, I'm not aware if it can be overridden by internal configuration changes.

"I want to be able to insert data in the existing column space and not create new column"
The cheat trick here would be to expand your expression language to existing 31 columns. 
Example 
Instead of using 
jx:each items=listOfObjects var=current area=AE2

Directly reference your objects from listOfObjects as:
A, B, C,... 
listOfObjects[0].property, listOfObjects[1].property, listOfObjects[2].property

Answer (score 0):

To perserve cell location as defined in the original template you should keep each jx:each statement in separate top level jx:area. So if A2 until C4 need to be filled dynamically from a list, but cells D2 until E4 will be statically filled and you do now want them to shift, you should define 2 areas:

- Note in Cell A1 (header): jx:area(lastCell="C4")
- Note in Cell A2: jx:each(items="employees" var="employee" lastCell="C2")
- Note in Cell D1: jx:area(lastCell="E4")